# Reading last returned value from console

Tags: python, python-2.7

Before reading the last returned values, there is a line to call a bash command with few variables in console. This bash command return a value but of course in bash screen. My question is how can I read this value as fast as possible to process the other lines.

I am using 'call' function from subprocess libraries to call a bash command

`call(["some", "words", "and", "variables"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to reply my question.
First I changed the 'calling method'. As I said, I was using 'subprocess.call' function as,

`call(["some", "words", "and", "variables"])`

Changed

```
  p = Popen(["some", "words", "and", "variables"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

in order to reach to output(also erros) of this command, we can use    `communicate()` function.

```
outputs, errors = p.communicate()
```

first element of communicate is outputs, second one is errors. But note that, these values returning as string value.